# jQuery backgroundColor animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a DIV with a link and a SPAN.

When clicking the link, it renders a list of items by using AJAX. When an item is clicked, the content of the SPAN is changed.

I want to highlight this change, by setting the background-color of the DIV to green, and animating it back to white using jQuery.

```
  var originalColor = elementToUpdate.parentNode.style.backgroundColor;
  elementToUpdate.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //lastSender.style.color;
  jQuery(elementToUpdate.id).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 1000);
```

The background of the SPAN is changed to green on the 2nd line, but the 3rd line doesn't do anything. No errors, or changes what so ever...

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** As noted by Ted Naleid in a comment below:

> Also note that you have to have the
>   color animations plugin installed for
>   this to work
>   (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color),
>   if you don't have it installed, jQuery
>   can't animate colors, only numeric
>   properties (at least as of 1.3.1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `.id` if you already have the element.  Hand it directly to jQuery:

```
jQuery(elementToUpdate).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 1000);
```

You don't get an error because `elementToUpdate.id` is a string, which jQuery (probably) interprets as a selector.  It just happens to be a selector that doesn't select anything.

Alternatively, you can say this to make it a valid selector:

```
jQuery('#' + elementToUpdate.id).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 1000);
```

But I think the first form is preferable since you already have the element itself.

Comment: Also note that you have to have the color animations plugin installed for this to work (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), if you don't have it installed, jQuery can't animate colors, only numeric properties (at least as of 1.3.1).

Comment: Good point, the OP didn't mention this so I'll add it to his question.