# Jquery hover - How to make background color animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="post_each">
    <h1 class="post_title">Apartamentos 1 comodo</h1>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb last" src="1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="post_each">
    <h1 class="post_title">Apartamentos 2 comodo</h1>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb" src="1.jpg"/>
    <img class="thumb last" src="1.jpg"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('img.thumb').hover(function {
        $(this).animate({"background" : "white"}, 600);
    });
</script>
```

hover() is not working at all. I just try to set either background color or border size should be increased when mouse hover.

Comment: Unless you've got another plugin, or you're using jQuery UI, jQuery can't animate colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t animate colors (at least this way), only properties with one numeric value are allowed. There is a separate color animation plugin you need to add.

That anonymous function is missing parentheses:

```
$('img.thumb').hover(function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jquery....

```
.thumb {
background: #000;
transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-o-transition: 0.5s;}

.thumb:hover {
background: #fff;
transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-o-transition: 0.5s;}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/fvac8/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use color plugin.. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

```
$('img.thumb').hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 600);
});
```

you can also refer previous threads [jQuery backgroundColor animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425082/jquery-backgroundcolor-animation) and [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)